# What is "Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale ar_EG" exception on glassfish server?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

**Overview**
This is calculator Web application On IBM Website about JavaServer Faces Tutorial.
I'm writing this application like the auditor exactly said .

*Points :*

- I'm not handling any Location or language issues cause the project doesn't need this.
- just faces-config.xml have `<message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>`.

**any hint to solve the problem , thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception message and the `<message-bundle>` configuration, at least the following files are missing in the classpath. The first two are not required, the last one is.

- `messages_ar_EG.properties` (contains country specific text)
- `messages_ar.properties` (contains language specific text)
- `messages.properties` (contains default localized text)

Either provide them, or if you don't want to provide custom messages at all, then just *remove* the whole `<message-bundle>` entry. JSF will then use the builtin messages.

Comment: You're welcome. The way as you configured it, it needs to go in the root of the classpath (there where all your packages root).